# When a name should be on a paper as an author in computer science?

Tags: publications, conference, authorship

I am working on using machine learning approaches for medical image analysis. What is the minimum requirement for someone to be added as a co-author in a conference paper?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, all authors need to contribute to the intellectual content of the paper. They all need to, somehow, be involved in its writing, if nothing more than approving what is written or offering suggestions.

It isn't time and effort that makes you an author. It is possible for a person to make a contribution worthy of authorship in a single short conversation, though that isn't the norm.

Some fields have their own rules. If a PI, for example, sets the direction of all research in a lab and funds the operation, they might validly claim authorship.

See, for example: https://provost.yale.edu/policies/academic-integrity/guidance-authorship-scholarly-or-scientific-publications

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.